# Concerning Electrogravitics in an inertial frame

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, quantum-electrodynamics

Listening to Feynman, He pointed out the fact that if a magnet is in an inertial frame with respect to a coil, there can be no electromotive force and hence no electricity produced. It is only when the magnet is moving with respect to the coil that there is electricity. That got me thinking, the same thing happens with time dilation. In that when an observer is in an inertial frame with the subject, they both experience the same time. But when the subject is moving time dilates or contracts. Is this just a coincidence, allegory, or are the two experiences related?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the two effects are very much related! I don't know how your background is, so let me start by defining the four-vector $x^\mu=(t,x,y,z)=(t,\vec{x})$ such that $x^0=t$ and $x_i=x,y,z$ for $i=1,2,3$. (Note that it is convention that greek indices run from $0$ to $3$ (space-time) while latin indices run from $1$ to $3$ (space only). Summation over double indices is implied.).

The eigentime $\tau$ of an observer is defined as the time in the frame where he is not moving, such that $ds^2=dt^2-d\vec{x}^2=d\tau^2$ since $d\vec{x}=0$ in this frame.

The four-velocity is then defined to be $$u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau}\right)=\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau},\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)=\left(\gamma,\gamma\vec{v}\right)$$ In the frame, where the observer is not moving, his own velocity is then $u^\mu=(1,\vec{0})$.

Now that we dealt with the special relativity part, let's have a look at electrodynamics. First, let's define the electromagnetic field strength tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ by

$$F^{0i}=-E_i/c=-F_{i0},\,  F_{ij}=-\epsilon_{ijk}B_k$$
and zero diagonal. As you can see, it is antisymmetric in its indices. In matrix notation it looks like:

$$F^{\mu\nu} = \left(\begin{matrix}
                  0  &   -E_x/c &  -E_y/c &  -E_z/c \\
                 E_x/c &   0  &  -B_z & B_y \\
                 E_y/c & B_z &   0  &  -B_x \\
                 E_z/c &  -B_y & B_x &   0  \\
       \end{matrix}\right)$$

The Lorentz force acting on a point charge with mass $m$ and charge $q$ in this formalism is described by

$$f^\mu=m\frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}=qF^{\mu\nu}u_\nu$$

You can check that in the non-relativistic limit $\gamma\rightarrow 1$ the special part of it reduces to the classical formula

$$\vec F=q(\vec v\times\vec B+\vec E)$$

Let's come to the point now. In the rest frame of the charge, we have $u_\mu=(1,\vec 0)$. Therefore

$$f^i=qF^{i\nu}u_\nu=qF^{i0}u_0=qF^{i0}=qE_i/c$$

which is only the electrical force. Any magnetic force drops out due to the fact that in the rest frame $u^i=0$ and the magnetic field only appears in the spacial part $F^{ij}$ of the field strength tensor.

But now we can apply a Lorentz transformation to see what happens in a frame where the charge is moving. In this case we have $u^\mu=\left(\gamma,\gamma\vec{v}\right)$ and therefore:

$$f^i=qF^{i\nu}u_\nu=q(F^{i0}u_0+F^{ij}u_j)=q(\gamma E_i/c+\epsilon_{ijk}B_k \gamma v_j)=q\gamma(E_i/c+(\vec v\times \vec B)_i)$$

so we indeed get a force by the magnetic field.

But how do we get from $u^\mu=(1,\vec 0)$ to $\tilde u^\mu=(\gamma,\gamma\vec v)$? Precisely by a Lorentz transformation!

$$\tilde u^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_\nu u^\nu=\Lambda^\mu_0=(\gamma,\gamma \vec v)$$

So here you have the connection between time dilatation and the action of the magnetic force: Both occur if you do a Lorentz transformation into a moving frame.

Comment: You know Years ago I started studying Calc. to understand aspects of power production. I started trying to understand advanced math because I found it difficult to read OTC science books. The first I have down ( pretty much) the second is a work in progress. Thanks for my next mathematical foray.

Comment: Actually, the main point is, that the magnetic force is only acting on charges that are moving and also the time dilatation only appears in a moving frame. Your main question, however, should be why the magnetic force only acts on moving charges, and this is not being answered by the math above. Ultimately, the answer is: because we measure it to be this way.